# Pulling Comments File Property to Text File

Tags: powershell

I am currently extracting the Name, FullName, BaseName from file's in a directory into a text file. I am also wanting to extract the 'Comments' field from the properties of the files I am looking at to the same text file.

Is this possible with Get-ChildItem or would I need to use something different?

```
    Get-ChildItem "\\otahnas02\TCG\Embroidery"  | Select Name, FullName, BaseName,
  @{ n = 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }, `
  @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-2] } } | Sort-Object name |
    Export-Csv "\\nzsdf01\c$\SCRIPTS\EmbroideryUpdateDirectory.txt" -Encoding Utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

I have tried adding Comments to the select of the script, although this doesn't work. I'm guessing the Comments property isn't part of Get-ChildItem? Not a powershell expert.

[Image of Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zum90.png)

Comment: Hi Carlos, If you do:  Get-ChildItem "\\otahnas02\TCG\Embroidery" | Get-Member, Is there a Property Member Type that matches what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below selects the Comments field and all other properties I need. Sorting the list by name.

```
Get-FileMetaData -folder "C:\pics" | select 'Name', 'Path', 'Comments' | Sort-Object Name |
Export-CSV "C:\pics\textfile.csv" -encoding Utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Only issue is this takes more time to execute than my original code.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky. It looks like you're trying to retrieve meta data **in the image**, not properties of the file. Windows Explorer by default will show meta data of many files (music, photos, etc)

MSFT wrote a function [`Get-FileMetadata`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804) that you could use to accomplish this with standard image files and a few other extensions.

If this is a proprietary file (Illustrator?) you'll have to use an Adobe library to read the file contents.  See  [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2243621).

Best of luck

Comment: Doesn't Seem like the Metadata has comments in it on my test. This is a very tricky on indeed.

Comment: The only reason I said the properties of the file is because of Right Click > Properties > Details Tab. These are generic .jpg/.png files. What I am trying to achieve is noting a bunch of comments against files that then get passed to different software via the text file i'm exporting. I'll have a go with Get-FileMetadata and see what I end up with.

Comment: If I use $picMetadata = Get-FileMetaData -folder (Get-childitem C:\pics -Recurse -Directory).FullName powershell is complaining Get-FileMetaData isn't recognised as a command. Any ideas?

Comment: If I use $picMetadata  = Get-FileMetaData -folder (Get-childitem "c:\pics" -Recurse -Directory).FullName this will return the camera model field which I can use to store comments, although powershell is saying a parameter cannot be found that matches -folder.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out in your answer. Unfortunately you have to run Get-FileMetaData against the folder and then filter the folder. Glad it works for you :)