# Having trouble executing MSFT's Get-FileMetaData function to extract file explorer comments field to csv or text file

Tags: powershell

I am hopelessly unlearned in powershell and need to extract file names and the comments field from filer explorer. A similar question was asked in [Pulling Comments File Property to Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892554/pulling-comments-file-property-to-text-file) but they were extracting info from an image file. I cannot figure out how to do the simpler thing of extracting the comments from the files directly (specifically .mp4 files)

The first comment suggests using MSFT's Get-FileMetaData function. I `Install-Module -Name FC_SysAdmin`. Running Powershell x86 (version 5) as an admin, I execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and then `Import-Module -Name FC_SysAdmin`. I should now be able to execute the code the author of the linked post gives in their answer, `Get-FileMetaData -folder "C:\pics" | select 'Name', 'Path', 'Comments' | Sort-Object Name | Export-CSV "C:\pics\textfile.csv" -encoding Utf8 -NoTypeInformation`. I get the error *Get-FileMetaData : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'folder'.* The author of the linked post also had this issue but seemed to be able to fix it themselves. I cannot. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters to the function:
`Get-Help Get-FileMetaData`
This returns some help and syntax information. In my case:
SYNTAX
Get-FileMetaData [-file] <Object[]> [[-properties] <String[]>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] []

Turns out the error is correct. The function in the [FC_SysAdmin](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FC_SysAdmin/5.0.0) package takes a -file parameter, not a folder parameter. So the examples and the actual code have different parameter names. Which is something that should be fixed by the author of the function, because it's confusing for the people following the examples.

I can't find the source for the original function from the Scripting Guy blog, but it looks like the original function, which required the folder parameter to point to a folder, was changed to take a file instead. So the name of the parameter was also changed to make that clear. But not in the examples...