# PowerShell - How to get the Tags and Comments property of a file

Tags: powershell, filesystems, file-properties

I would like to write a PowerShell script to access the Tags and Comment property of a file
We can see it in file explorer

or in file > Properties > Details

I try to use
Get-MetaData

it not recognized I probably have to install a module but I could not find which one.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467821/get-filemetadata-not-cmdlet-in-powershell and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892554/pulling-comments-file-property-to-text-file

Comment: Document properties aren't _file-system_ metadata (such as the file size), they are embedded in a file itself. There is no built-in PowerShell cmdlet to retrieve them, but you can use the `Shell.Application` COM object to read (but not write) them. See the linked duplicate for details.